# Compatibility between Presheaf Pullback Functor and Sheafification

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $Y$ be a scheme and $\mathcal{G}$ a *presheaf* on any reasonble site over $X$;  to have something concrete in mind let's take the small etale site $X_{\text{et}}$. Let furthermore $f:X \to Y$ any morphism of schemes.

There exist a presheaf pullback functor $f^P$ associating to $\mathcal{G}$  a presheaf on $X$ defined on sections by: For any etale $V \to X$ define

$$ f^P\mathcal{G}(V):= \varinjlim_U \mathcal{G}(U)  $$

where the direct limit runs over etale $U \to Y$ through which the composition $V \to X \to Y$ factors. If $\mathcal{G}$ is a sheaf, the presheaf $f^P\mathcal{G}$ is in general not neccessarily a sheaf.

The "usual" pullback $f^*\mathcal{G}$ is defined as composition of $f^P$ with $s(-)$ the sheafification functor, a functor associating naturally a sheaf to a presheaf.

In general so far I know, the presheaf pullback functor not commutes with sheafification in the sense that for a presheaf $\mathcal{G}$

$$   s(f^P(s(\mathcal{G}))) \neq s(f^P(\mathcal{G})) $$

Or am I wrong with this claim and the two sheaves are always isomorphic? If not, can one in general at least say to how badly the sheaves $   s(f^P(s(\mathcal{G}))) $ and $s(f^P(\mathcal{G})) $ could differ from each over? Are there criteria when they coinside, beyond the "stupid" case when $f^P$ maps sheaves to sheaves, compare Milne's Etale Cohomology, Remark 2.14 (b), p 63 (the book, not the online script).

Comment: I'm surprised by the assumption that those sheaves should be different. There is a natural morphism $s(f^P(\mathcal G))\to s(f^P(s(\mathcal G)))$ and it induces an isomorphism of stalks at all geometric points (doesn't it?), hence is an isomorphism (isn't it?)

Comment: Yeah, just combine https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03PT and https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03PU (I'm not in the mood to write a formal answer today, everybody please feel free to do that. Otherwise, I might revisit this tomorrow...)

Comment: @Ben: Thanks, now it's crystal clear, my assumpion was simply wrong. I would like just to add that it seems that this commutativity between sheafification functor and pullback seemingly doesn't work for pushforward functor $f_*$ as well (...even if from naive point view one might expect that it behaves more nicely with respect sheafification as it maps sheaves to sheaves). The point seems to lie on even if by universal property of sheafification there exist a canonical "comparison" map $s(f_* \mathcal{P}) \to f_*(s(\mathcal{P}))$, in general we cannot say much about difference of

Comment: stalks $(f_* \mathcal{P})_x$ and  $(f_*(s(\mathcal{P}))_x$ for proper presheaf $\mathcal{P}$, at least if one insists on arbitrary $f$, right? (eg for $f$ closed immersion, it's a iso, but even for open immersion at points not in the image that might stay obscure so far know) Or can one still say something more on the story with pushforwards?

Comment: Stalks of direct images can be pretty wild, yes. I don't know.

Comment: Yeah, take $Y=\mathsf{Spec}(\mathbb C)$, $X=Y\amalg Y$ with the obvious map $f\colon X\to Y$. On $X$, consider a constant pre-sheaf $\mathcal F=\underline A$ for a finite, non-empty set $A$. Then $f_*\mathcal F(Y)=A\neq A\amalg A=f_*s(\mathcal F)(Y)$.